# TCL - undefined reference to `_imp__Tcl_ResetResult' for g++

Tags: c++, r, tcl, swig

I am relatively new to TCL and I am trying to execute a C++ program using SWIG on Windows 10. Using command prompt. I am not using Visual Studio
I am basically trying to run r_cpp using C++ MinGW from TCL

```
C:\swigwin-3.0.12\Examples\r\class>swig -c++ -tcl example.i`
C:\swigwin-3.0.12\Examples\r\class>g++ -c example.cxx
C:\swigwin-3.0.12\Examples\r\class>g++ -c example_wrap.cxx -I/Tcl/include/tcl8.6
C:\swigwin-3.0.12\Examples\r\class>g++ -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o example.dll
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x981): undefined reference to `_imp__Tcl_ResetResult'`example_wrap.o:example_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x995): undefined reference to `_imp__Tcl_SetObjResult'`example_wrap.o:example_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x9b9): undefined reference to `_imp__Tcl_SetErrorCode'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x9cf): undefined reference to `_imp__Tcl_ResetResult'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x9f3): undefined reference to `_imp__Tcl_SetErrorCode
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xa1e): undefined reference to `_imp__Tcl_AppendResult'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xa3c): undefined reference to `_imp__Tcl_NewStringObj'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone please help me on this??
Should I make changes to my Makefile.in in the folder?????

Comment: You probably need to link with Tcl's import library

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I've done C but I would think that you are not linking in the static/shared library that has the functions that g++ is complaining about.  In this case the tcl library something like libTclXX.dll.   I'm not too familiar with command lines on windows but  something like -llibtclXX.dll -L path_to_tcllib could be added. If I recall correctly tcl does provide a stub library for you to link staticially your extension then at runtime the shared library can be use to resolve the functions... so something like -llibtclstubs.dll . look in your installed lib  directory for actual names of these libraries.

Comment: Thank You fixed the issue by adding -ltcl86.dll to the -L path